# Reading Plain Text in a Google Sheet to an Array with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, types, google-sheets

The Google Sheet Script that I will paste below searches through our teams sheets and compares the information in the cells to a criteria. If the criteria is not met, the cell is highlighted and the information is put into an array which is sent over email.

I have a few scripts very similar to this one that work fine but when I try to read the contents of a cell that might contain "UMVTC5", the information that is stored in the Array is undefined.

I have tried the .toString method but this does not work for the type undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Tanner

Code :

```
 function ifstatement() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//sheet activation
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Testing Pass/Fail");


  var rangeData =sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();                       
  var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
  var searchRange = sheet.getRange(2,2,lastRow+1,lastColumn+1);   
  var rangeValues = searchRange.getValues();
  var background = searchRange.getBackgrounds();

  var DevolID = [];
  var DevolID_Fail = [];

  var value = "Fail";


  //Loop through the sheet
  for (i=0; i < lastColumn -1; i++){
   for(j=0; j< lastRow -1; j++){

      //If the sheet is less than value and not blank
      if((rangeValues[j][i]) == value && (rangeValues[j][i]) != ""){  


        //Highlight the affected percentage
        sheet.getRange(j+2,i+2).setBackground("#8190ff");

         //If the cell is not blank and the background has not 
         been marked
          if((rangeValues[j][i]!= ""&&background[j][i]!="#8190ff" )){


           //Put the DevolID in the Arrray 
           DevolID_Fail.push(rangeValues[j][i-1]+ " ");


          //Show the Testing Status of the Batch ID 
           DevolID_Fail.push(rangeValues[j][i]+" ");   


           //Log the DevolID Array
           Logger.log('Devol ID_Yield %s :\n ',DevolID_Fail);


               }
           }


      else {
        sheet.getRange(j+2,i+2).setBackground("");
       }; 
    };

  };

if (DevolID_Fail.length > 0){


sendEmail(DevolID_Fail);



};

 DevolID_Fail.length = 0;


};


      function sendEmail(DevolID_Fail){

     var tanner="hi@gmail.com";
     var subject="Yield Threshold Failure ";
     var Log = Logger.getLog();
     var body= "Devol ID Failed Pesticide: "+DevolID_Fail;
     MailApp.sendEmail(tanner,subject,body);
```

Output : undefined ,Fail

the sheet that I log this information from looks something like this

```
       Batch ID STATUS
       YOLP34    Pass
       DGWBC4    Pass
       RRPFB4    Pass
       YYFBC4    Fail
       EPFBC4    Fail
```

The script looks through the cells and highlights and saves all Failed Batch ID STATUS to an array. If it is highlighted already it will be skipped and if none are put into the array the email doesn't send so only new information is sent out. I control how many get sent out currently and that works great, I do not know how to format the output though.

The undefined portion needs to display what is read "EPFBC4" but currently displays "undefined"

Thank you,
Tanner Osborn

Comment: Your question is unclear, your script seems to be looking for the value "Fail". However, in the question, you seem to mention the script is supposed to looking for "UMVTC5". The script Outputs :undefined, fail, however, the code doesn't seem to output anything! Do you mean it logs this?

Comment: An example sheet data and a better explanation of what this current script is doing vs what you expect it do will help users understand the query better!

Comment: Sorry first post just added more above.

Comment: When i=0 this `rangeValues[j][i-1]!= ""` is undefined because indices must be between 0 and `rangeValue[j].length-1`

Comment: I changed that criteria but I do not think that it is the source of the problem. That portion just checks if the current cell is blank or highlighted and if they are neither the program continues. I tested this again with the same output of my Batch ID showing undefined.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for your help. I hope the additional explanation provides some insight.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [mcve]